# Loading a template for a URL pattern

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, page-template, gallery

I am creating gallery pages for events and csr-events custom post type.

Now it has three types of pages:

1. www.example.com/gallery
2. www.example.com/gallery/events
3. www.example.com/gallery/csr-events

I have programatically created pages for the above slugs using wp_insert_post:
Example for events gallery:

```
    wp_insert_post(
        array(
            'comment_status' => 'closed',
            'ping_status' => 'closed',
            'post_author' => 1,
            'post_parent' => $page['parent'],
            'post_name' => $page['slug'],
            'post_title' => $page['title'],
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => $page['post-type'],
            'page_template' => $page['template'],
        )
    );
```

So the pagenames are gallery,events and csr-events.

I have set gallery as a parent page and events and csr-events as child of gallery.

And then in template-gallery.php I check the `$wp_query->query_vars['pagename']`
Which gives me gallery or events or csr-events.
And based on this I write a query to get images.

I have created an archive list for the these 3 gallery pages by making some changes in [this plugin](https://github.com/jacklenox/archives-for-custom-post-types)  which returns URL in this format :

1. http://www.example.com/gallery/2015/09
2. http://www.example.com/gallery/events/2015/08
3. http://www.example.com/gallery/csr-events/2015/09
4. For other archive pages having custom post type it returns : http://www.example.com/events/2015/09

and I made changes in the rewrite rule of the plugin which works for other custom post types but does not work for gallery pages :

```
$line_separated = implode( '|', $post_types );//works for events/
$newrules['(' . $line_separated . ')/(\d*)/(\d*)$'] = 'index.php?post_type=$matches[1]&m=$matches[2]$matches[3]';
```

What rewrite rule should I use here for http://www.example.com/gallery/events/2015/08 to work.

I tried this

```
$newrules['gallery/events/(\d*)/(\d*)$'] = 'index.php?pagename=events&m=$matches[1]$matches[2]';
```

but it just loads gallery/events and removes the year and month
What rewrite rule can I use to load the events page and persist the url such that I can get year and month in the `m` .

Note : gallery is not a custom post type here. It is just a page.

Answer (score 0):

To determine the best filter to use, you have to determine what those pages are. Is `is_page()` true? Use the `page_template` filter. Is `is_post_type_archive()` true? Use the `archive_template` filter.

[All of the query type-specific template filters are listed here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#filter-hierarchy).

You can also use the generic [`template_include`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include), which fires for all types.

Within any of these filters you can check the same conditions you need to determine if you need to load the `template-gallery.php` template.

Comment: Thanks @Milo you have been very helpful. What can be the condition to make sure it loads this template for for these urls. Because is_page will not work for this case.

Comment: These url's were created by me by just changing the output of the plugin. So these url's got no data registered with wordpress.

Comment: That plugin generates some type of main query. `var_dump($wp_query)` for those requests, what do you see?

Comment: I did a var_dump($wp_query) in template_include and here is the output http://pastebin.com/i39xxsPv .

Comment: `is_404` is true for those queries. that plugin seems to be doing something incorrectly.

Comment: I have added the changes I made in the plugin. I might have not done it in a correct way. Because the plugin works well in other cases. I just changed the url the plugin gives as output. I am not sure about what else data I should add in the plugin to make some sense out of this url.

Comment: I have made many changes in the plugin and have reached a little closer . It would be great if you can show me some direction to move forward.Have been trying for many hours now.

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is now exactly. I have no way of testing anything because I don't know what your actual code is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31521/discussion-between-roshan-and-milo).